# Android Beam - Must Extend Activity?

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I am trying to incorporate Android Beam into my app. But, I need to extend another class instead of Activity for my app. When I try doing this:

```
public class SomeClass extends AnotherActivity implements
            CreateNdefMessageCallback{
```

Android Beam doesn't work at all, the Touch to Beam doesn't show up. However, when I do this:

```
public class SomeClass extends Activity implements
            CreateNdefMessageCallback{
```

Android Beam works fine. AnotherActivity extends some other activities which eventually extends Activity itself, so I have no idea why Android Beam isn't working in the first case. Does anyone know why this happens?

Here is more of the original, Android Beam not working code for reference.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback;
import android.nfc.NfcEvent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class SomeClass extends AnotherActivity implements
        CreateNdefMessageCallback{
    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    TextView mInfoText;
    private static final int MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
    private NdefMessage message;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Check for available NFC Adapter
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Register callback to set NDEF message
        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);

    }

    /**
     * Implementation for the CreateNdefMessageCallback interface
     */

    @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        String text = ("Beam me up, Android!\n\n" +
                "Beam Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(
                new NdefRecord[] {
                    NdefRecord.createMime(
                            "application/vnd.com.example.android.beam",
                            text.getBytes())
                });
        return msg;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check to see that the Activity started due to an Android Beam
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            processIntent(getIntent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // onResume gets called after this to handle the intent
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Parses the NDEF Message from the intent and prints to the TextView
     */
    void processIntent(Intent intent) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent
                .getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        // only one message sent during the beam
        NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
        // record 0 contains the MIME type, record 1 is the AAR, if present
        mInfoText.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload()));
    }
}
```

I have checked the differences between the two in DDMS LogCat. Here is the log using AnotherActivity (NFC doesn't work)

```
07-14 13:53:10.317: W/NFC-LLC(608): LLC length mis-match
07-14 13:53:12.747: I/NFC-HCI(608): I'm P2P Passive Target @ 212 kb/s
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): Discovered P2P Initiator
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 46 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 66 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 6d 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 01 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 01 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 11 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 03 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 02 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 00 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 13 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 04 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 01 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NFCJNI(608): 96 
07-14 13:53:12.754: D/NfcService(608): LLCP Activation message
07-14 13:53:12.762: I/NFCJNI(608): LLCP Link activated (LTO=150, MIU=128, OPTION=0x00, WKS=0x13)
07-14 13:53:12.762: I/NfcP2pLinkManager(608): LLCP activated
07-14 13:53:12.762: D/NfcP2pLinkManager(608): onP2pInRange()
07-14 13:53:12.778: D/NfcP2pLinkManager(608): onP2pSendConfirmationRequested()
07-14 13:53:12.934: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.open locked: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=false tryLock=0ms
07-14 13:53:12.942: D/NFCJNI(608): Unable to open SE connection, device already connected to a P2P peer or a Tag
07-14 13:53:13.950: D/NFCJNI(608): Unable to open SE connection, device already connected to a P2P peer or a Tag
07-14 13:53:14.958: D/NFCJNI(608): Unable to open SE connection, device already connected to a P2P peer or a Tag
07-14 13:53:15.965: D/NFCJNI(608): Unable to open SE connection, device already connected to a P2P peer or a Tag
07-14 13:53:16.981: D/NFCJNI(608): Unable to open SE connection, device already connected to a P2P peer or a Tag
07-14 13:53:17.989: D/NFCJNI(608): Unable to open SE connection, device already connected to a P2P peer or a Tag
07-14 13:53:18.997: D/NFCJNI(608): Unable to open SE connection, device already connected to a P2P peer or a Tag
07-14 13:53:20.012: D/NFCJNI(608): Unable to open SE connection, device already connected to a P2P peer or a Tag
07-14 13:53:20.801: I/NFCJNI(608): LLCP Link deactivated
07-14 13:53:20.809: D/NfcService(608): LLCP Link Deactivated message. Restart polling loop.
07-14 13:53:20.809: I/NfcP2pLinkManager(608): LLCP deactivated.
07-14 13:53:21.184: E/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.open() re-enabling card emulation
07-14 13:53:21.192: I/NfcAdapterExtras(2915): Wakelock WakeLock{41439a78 held=true, refCount=1} acquired 1405364001194 ms
07-14 13:53:21.192: I/NfcAdapterExtras(2915): Wakelock WakeLock{41439a78 held=true, refCount=1} released 1405364001198 ms elapsed 4 ms
07-14 13:53:21.192: I/NfcAdapterExtras(2915): Wakelock WakeLock{41439a78 held=true, refCount=1} acquired 1405364001199 ms
07-14 13:53:21.200: I/NfcAdapterExtras(2915): Wakelock WakeLock{41439a78 held=true, refCount=1} released 1405364001202 ms elapsed 3 ms
07-14 13:53:21.200: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.open  ++: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, SecureElement] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=2
07-14 13:53:21.200: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.open  ++: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, SecureElement, SecureElement] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=3
07-14 13:53:21.200: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.open  ++: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, SecureElement, SecureElement, ControllerApplet] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=4
07-14 13:53:21.262: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.close --: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, SecureElement, SecureElement, ControllerApplet] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=4
07-14 13:53:21.262: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.close --: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, SecureElement, SecureElement] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=3
07-14 13:53:21.262: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.close --: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, SecureElement] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=2
07-14 13:53:21.262: W/NfcEventServiceWorker(2915): Payments are activated failure: com.google.android.apps.embeddedse.iso7816.SecureElementAppletFileNotFoundException: ControllerApplet: SELECT a0000004762010: statusWord=0x6a82 (File Not Found)
07-14 13:53:21.262: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.open  ++: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, MifareManagerImpl] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=2
07-14 13:53:21.270: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.open  ++: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, MifareManagerImpl, MifareManagerImpl] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=3
07-14 13:53:21.270: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.close --: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, MifareManagerImpl, MifareManagerImpl] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=3
07-14 13:53:21.270: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.open  ++: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, MifareManagerImpl, MifareApplet] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=3
07-14 13:53:21.340: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.close --: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, MifareManagerImpl, MifareApplet] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=3
07-14 13:53:21.348: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.close --: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker, MifareManagerImpl] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true holdCount=2
07-14 13:53:21.364: D/NfcService(608): NFC-EE ON
07-14 13:53:21.372: D/NfcService(608): NFC-C ON
07-14 13:53:21.395: I/NfcExecutionEnvironment(2915): NFCEE.close closed: stack=[NfcEventServiceWorker] openTid=263 nfceeOpened=true tryLock=0ms session=8460ms
07-14 13:53:21.559: D/NfcP2pLinkManager(608): Debounce timeout
07-14 13:53:21.559: D/NfcP2pLinkManager(608): onP2pOutOfRange()
07-14 13:53:21.770: I/NfcEventServiceWorker(2915): Waiting ...
```

Comment: Are you using/activating any other NFC functionality in `AnotherActivity` (or any of its super-classes)?

Comment: No, this is the only class which uses NFC.

Comment: I have added the LogCat of AnotherActivity (NFC doesn't work) to the bottom of the question. I hope someone understands the lower level stuff more than I.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. In AnotherActivity (or in my case, class C where AnotherActivity extends A which extends B which extends C) I had the following line of code.

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

This disables the taking of screenshots which is essential for the Android Beam UI ("Touch to Beam") to function. Without the UI, Android Beam will not work at all. The solution was to do the following in AnotherActivity:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Everything works fine now.